# The 'host_compress_magento_code' provisioner could not be found

Tags: vagrant

So I'm trying to install a second vagrant VM, specifically configured for Magento 2. Which I found here: https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers
on windows 10.

I couldn't clone the repository, because I got "Access denied", so instead I just downloaded the rar and extracted it into a folder.

Afterwards I launched my GitBash and did "vagrant up" into the folder.
After about an hour of downloading I get this error:

"There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The 'host_compress_magento_code' provisioner could not be found."

Additionally it had a problem with hosts manager as well, but I quickly found out I can do "vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager" and it solved that error, but the missing "host_compress_magento_code" continues to not let me up the vagrant.

In "Vagrantfile" I found the following line:

config.vm.provision "host_compress_magento_code", type: "host_shell", inline: "tar -cf scripts/host/magento2ce.tar magento2ce"

Quick search about the command lead me to believe that it needs "magento2ce" file in the vagrant root dir in order to create that "magento2ce.tar" archive. 
But I have no clue what that file should be.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Google searches just lead to threads where "vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager" has been the solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After cloning of [Vagrant Box for Magento 2 Developers](https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers) you should (simplified version):

1. Copy `etc/composer/auth.json.dist` to `etc/composer/auth.json`.
2. Add the Magento Marketplace keys for Marketplace authorization to the repo.magento.com section.
3. Run `init_project.sh`

Please, read more carefully [Installation steps](https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers#installation-steps)  section. It contains more details of how you can configure and work with this vagrant box.

`init_project.sh` install all needed vagrant plugins and after that run `vagrant up`. After you init of project you can work as ordinary `vagrant suspend`, `vagrant resume` and etc